# Uninstalling OSX-AVR from Mac OS X 10.7.2

Tags: macos, avr-gcc

Does anyone know how to completely remove OSX-AVR from Mac OS X?  I need newer support for avr-gcc, so I am going to install CrossPack for AVR, but I do not want any collisions from having multiple avr-gccs in my system.  I have not found any documentation about uninstalling OSX-AVR, so I do not know how to get rid of everything.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Took me a while to find this but sometimes you have to install to uninstall, from the readme that popups after you install (located locally at /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/manual/installation.html):

```
sudo /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether there is a bom file for this installation. It might be in /Library/Receipts or ~/Library/Receipts. This file (you can view its content with lsbom) contains a list of all files belonging to an installation.
But I'm not sure whether OSX-AVR writes one.

Answer (score 0):

The which command will tell you in what directory your program is installed, and then you can move that file into the trash.

```
sudo mv `which <yourProgramName>` ~/.Trash/
```

I used this to uninstall AVRDUDE from my crosspack installation and it worked fine. Someone has commented that this will not get rid of any extra files that may have been installed in other directories which is true but hopefully those files would be overwritten upon reinstall. This worked fine in my case.

Comment: Can you write more details ?

Comment: This doesn't help if the program in question has installed utilities in other locations, which seems likely in the case of the program cited in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

`brew remove avrdude` worked for me (mac os x 10.11.4).